# Synchronize/ mutex for clustered tomcats

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, locking

I have a cluster that runs 3 tomcats, they run the same webapp and i have a load balancer too . I'm looking for a way to synchronize them via a mutex object.

I would like this object to be available for all the tomcats and that each can request a lock for it.
I would of used mysql db but i dont have it in my project.

I'm using java with spring 4 and mongodb.

thanks!

Comment: Is the database shared? In that case use that - dump the tasks into it and then take and delete them. If you want to share actual variables, then use something like Terracotta.

Comment: Well, in that case you need to share _something_. The best solution would be a shared DB. You could use JMS, but it's an abuse really. Finally, you could use terracotta.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if you use Quartz and store it's data in DB, then there is ready solution for it:

org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered=true

Comment: That's good for schedule codeת is there a solution for locking in general?